# git merge shows Already-upto-date even though there are differences in two branches

Tags: git

In git when I try to merge two branches, I get the message "Already-upto-date". But if I manually compare the files in both the branches being merged I find differences. What can be the reason for this behavior. Please help me resolve this.

I have 2 branches Phoenix-0.5 and master-0.5.
i am currently in master-0.5 and I did 
git merge Phoenix-0.5

I get the message "Already-upto-date". But if I compare files manually in both the branches I find differences.

Comment: If the result of a merge were two identical branches, why would you merge at all?

Answer (score 3):

`git merge` is primarily making sure that all the changes that have been applied on `Phoenix-0.5` since it diverged from `master-0.5` have been applied to `master-0.5`. However, any changes made on `master-0.5` since the diversion will be retained (except in the case of conflicts, which will have needed manual resolution) in `master-0.5`. So, the end result of the merge is *not* that both branches are identical, and, in general, after a merge, you *should* expect to see a non-empty `git diff master-0.5 Phoenix-0.5` - the differences will be the changes made on `master-0.5` that were not made on `Phoenix-0.5`.